# RSpec model relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing relations between users. 
user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :following, class_name: 'Follower', foreign_key: :follower_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

follower model:

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

And failing test:

```
it 'should unfollow user' do
  @user.following.create(user_id: @user2.id, is_friend: false)
  post 'follow', id: @user2.id
  expect(response).to be_success
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(@user.following).to be_empty
end
```

I can rebuild it to get work:

```
it 'should unfollow user' do
  @user.following.create(user_id: @user2.id, is_friend: false)
  post 'follow', id: @user2.id
  expect(response).to be_success
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(Follower.where(follower_id: @user.id, user_id: @user2.id)).to be_empty
end
```

But i can't understand, why @user.following isn't empty? Method works fine and deleting entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you would need to call `@user.reload` to reload the @user object from the database, just before your last `expect` line. Until then, database changes don't modify an object you've already instantiated.

In an unrelated issue, I'm not sure why you're parsing the response body but doing nothing with it, unless it's to check for an exception when parsing the response. In that case, you might consider something like:

```
expect { JSON.parse(response.body) }.not_to raise_exception
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have skipped a part of code with matching json :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first test is checking the value of `following` within the Ruby `User` object. Since that object hasn't been reloaded/refreshed since the unfollow was done, it retains the original value.

Your second test is doing an SQL operation, which picks up the current information from the database.